# Transposing a table in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, transpose

I am using SQL Server 2005 for my application.
I have a table in my stored procedure which has two columns, C1 and C2. I want to transpose this table such that the values of column C1 becomes the columns.
Before transpose (Table 1):

```
C1  C2
M1  U1
M1  U2
M1  U3
M2  U4
M2  U5
```

After Transpose (Table 2):

```
M1  M2
U1  U4
U2  U5
U3  NULL
```

In Table1, the number of distinct values (M1, M2) may vary. So, the columns in Table2 are not fix.

Please provide a solution to achieve the same.

Comment: look up PIVOT with Dynamic SQL; this question has been answered several times before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [dynamic sql pivot in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327261/dynamic-sql-pivot-in-sql-server)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Answer (score 2):

For this type of data transformation you will want to use the `PIVOT` function that is available in SQL Server 2005+.  There are two ways to apply the *pivot* function.

If you know the values ahead of time, then you can hard-code the values in the query. Similar to this:

```
select M1, M2
from
(
  select c1, c2,
    row_number() over(partition by c1 order by c1, c2) rn
  from yourtable
) src
pivot
(
  max(c2)
  for c1 in (M1, M2)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/33fbb/6).

But if you have an unknown number of values that you want to transpose into columns, then you can use dynamic SQL to create the query at run-time.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(C1) 
                    from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select C1, C2,
                  row_number() over(partition by c1 order by c1, c2) rn
                from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(C2)
                for C1 in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/33fbb/7).

Both will give the same result, the difference is the dynamic version is flexible if the values will change:

```
| M1 |     M2 |
---------------
| U1 |     U4 |
| U2 |     U5 |
| U3 | (null) |
```

Comment: nice solution, but can you elaborate on what `row_number() over(partition by c1 order by c1, c2) rn` does in this case?

Comment: @JeremyS. When you are working with string values your options for aggregation are limited to `max` or `min`. As a result, if you do not use a `row_number` you will wind up with only one row.  The `row_number` with the `partition` generates a distinct value that keeps the values separated during the `group by`.  See [this demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/33fbb/21) to see what happens without the `row_number`, you only get one row.

Comment: thanks for the example, I saw that and still don't understand how MSSQL knows to consider ``row_number`` as a distinct value, it isn't included in the group by clause cause there is none, how come MSSQL knows that?

Comment: @JeremyS. The `PIVOT` is performing an aggregation and while the `group by` is not explicitly stated it is being used. I suggest reading the [PIVOT docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) on MSDN.  Or if you have a specific question, then post a new question. :)

Comment: Hello there, your transponation is very useful for me, but I can't use it on mysql server 5.1. I get an error regarding the "declare" thing at the beginning. What can I do to make this run?

Comment: @LStrike MySQL has different syntax to pivot data. Can you post a new question and then post a link here and I will take a look?

Comment: @bluefeet Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15810987/using-declare-in-mysql-5-1

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a case where dynamic sql is your friend. Assuming your base table's name is "Transpose":

```
--Get a Unique List of values from C1 --> These will be our column headers
DECLARE @Unique TABLE (C1 VARCHAR(25), fUsed BIT DEFAULT 0);
INSERT INTO @Unique (C1) SELECT DISTINCT C1 FROM Transpose;

DECLARE @TransSQL NVARCHAR(4000);
DECLARE @ColID NVARCHAR(25);

SET @TransSQL = N'SELECT ' 

--Loop over unique C1 values and construct the select statement
SELECT @ColID = (SELECT TOP 1 C1 FROM @Unique WHERE fUSed = 0);
WHILE @@ROWCOUNT <> 0 AND @ColID IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @TransSQL = @TransSQL + 'CASE C1 WHEN ' + '''' + @ColID + '''' + ' THEN C2 ELSE NULL END AS ' + @ColID + ', '

    --Update flag in table so we don't use this field again
    UPDATE u SET fUsed = 1 FROM @Unique u WHERE C1 = @ColID;
    SELECT @ColID = (SELECT TOP 1 C1 FROM @Unique WHERE fUSed = 0);
END

--Remove Trailing comma and add FROM clause
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @SQL = LEFT(@TransSQL,LEN(@TransSQL) -1) + ' FROM Transpose'

--For debugging purposes
PRINT @SQL;

--Execute the dynamic sql
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

This won't achieve the exact layout your question described because their isn't a key field to group the results by. Instead, the output will look like the following:

```
M1     M2      M3
U1     NULL    NULL
U2     NULL    NULL
U3     NULL    NULL
NULL   U4      NULL
NULL   U5      NULL
NULL   NULL    U6
```

If your base table has a key field the query can be modified slightly to group the results by the key field and probably come a bit closer to your stated goal for the resulting data.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply....is there any way to sort only a coulmn in SQL such that all other columns doesn't get sorted as a result. In excel, we can do this. Dont know about SQL Server. Please help if there is any way to do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

### This isnt exact result that you want but you can try this

```
;WITH TAB1 AS
( SELECT  [ResponsibleID] C1,[ActionID] C2,1 ORD
  FROM [TEST].[dbo].[yourtable]
  WHERE 1=1
  )


 SELECT 
    CASE WHEN M1=1 THEN ActionID ELSE NULL END M1,
    CASE WHEN M2=1 THEN ActionID ELSE NULL END M2 
 FROM TAB1
 PIVOT(AVG(ORD) FOR RESPONSIBLEID IN ([M1],[M2])) AS ABC
```