# SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I've been tasked with coming up with a means of translating the following data:

```
date        category        amount
1/1/2012    ABC             1000.00
2/1/2012    DEF             500.00
2/1/2012    GHI             800.00
2/10/2012   DEF             700.00
3/1/2012    ABC             1100.00
```

into the following:

```
date        ABC             DEF             GHI
1/1/2012    1000.00
2/1/2012                    500.00
2/1/2012                                    800.00
2/10/2012                   700.00
3/1/2012    1100.00
```

The blank spots can be NULLs or blanks, either is fine, and the categories would need to be dynamic. Another possible caveat to this is that we'll be running the query in a limited capacity, which means temp tables are out. I've tried to research and have landed on `PIVOT` but as I've never used that before I really don't understand it, despite my best efforts to figure it out. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 312, accepted):

Dynamic SQL PIVOT:

```
create table temp
(
    date datetime,
    category varchar(3),
    amount money
)

insert into temp values ('1/1/2012', 'ABC', 1000.00)
insert into temp values ('2/1/2012', 'DEF', 500.00)
insert into temp values ('2/1/2012', 'GHI', 800.00)
insert into temp values ('2/10/2012', 'DEF', 700.00)
insert into temp values ('3/1/2012', 'ABC', 1100.00)


DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.category) 
            FROM temp c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
    
set @query = 'SELECT date, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select date
                    , amount
                    , category
                from temp
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(amount)
                for category in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)

drop table temp
```

Results:

```
Date                        ABC         DEF    GHI
2012-01-01 00:00:00.000     1000.00     NULL    NULL
2012-02-01 00:00:00.000     NULL        500.00  800.00
2012-02-10 00:00:00.000     NULL        700.00  NULL
2012-03-01 00:00:00.000     1100.00     NULL    NULL
```

Comment: So \@cols must be string-concatenated, right? We can't use sp_executesql and parameter-binding to interpolate \@cols in there? Even though we construct \@cols ourself, what if somehow it contained malicious SQL. Any additional mitigating steps I could take before concatenating it and executing it?

Comment: How would you sort the rows and columns on this?

Comment: @PatrickSchomburg There are a variety of ways - if you wanted to sort the `@cols` then you could remove the `DISTINCT` and use `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` when you get the list of `@cols`.

Comment: I have the similar problem but Instead of Category I have the categoryId. Category name comes from a different table. So would that be possible to read the column header from another table?

Comment: @akd If I understand the questions correctly, you should be able to do this. You'd just have to join the tables in your PIVOT and query the other table when getting the `@cols`.

Comment: Thanks but I am not sure where the join should go n the query?

Comment: @akd Before trying to write it as a dynamic query, write it as a hard-coded version so you get the joins correct, then convert to dynamic.  That's going to be the easiest way to proceed.  Otherwise, you'll have to ask a new question about it, because it's going to be too difficult to try an debug in the comments.

Comment: Same here as @akd, I have a huge join block and a huge where block. Normally they are identical for both queries, the question is where am I supposed to put them ? Can they be put in one place only and used by both for easy editing of conditions later ?

Comment: @Enissay my suggestion would be to write the query as a static/hard coded version first, then convert it to dynamic sql. This allows you to get the logic and the result you want before diving into dynamic sql.

Comment: The dynamic query is working fine now. Do you have any elegant way to edit the WHERE clause only once so that it's applied to both queries ? (the goal is to edit at one place instead of two, given that the changes are identical)

Comment: This works perfectly. I just would like to learn what all this sentence means: 

STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.category) 
            FROM temp c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

Especially the part "FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')"

Comment: This solution is similar to this blog post, which worked great-- https://www.essentialsql.com/create-dynamic-pivot-table-sql-server/

Comment: Cool! Do you know of a way to add a prefix to the value column names - so you have a result with columns: date, Amount_ABC, Amount_DEF, Amount_GHI? I am asking, because I would like to join an additional value column to it and then I would need to distinguish between the amount columns and the additional value columns.

Comment: @schluk5 See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20999706/426671), you could concatenate the string that you want at the start of each column name.

Comment: Some improvements: More efficient to do `GROUP BY `c.category` rather than `DISTINCT` as it can rely on indexes. And `text()[1]` is more efficient than `.` in the XQuery. Also in newer versions you can use `STRING_AGG` instead of `FOR XML`.

Comment: So what's the reason for the rollback? Are these not good improvements?

Answer (score 41):

### Dynamic SQL PIVOT

Different approach for creating columns string

```
create table #temp
(
    date datetime,
    category varchar(3),
    amount money
)

insert into #temp values ('1/1/2012', 'ABC', 1000.00)
insert into #temp values ('2/1/2012', 'DEF', 500.00)
insert into #temp values ('2/1/2012', 'GHI', 800.00)
insert into #temp values ('2/10/2012', 'DEF', 700.00)
insert into #temp values ('3/1/2012', 'ABC', 1100.00)

DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='';
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='';

SELECT @cols = @cols + QUOTENAME(category) + ',' FROM (select distinct category from #temp ) as tmp
select @cols = substring(@cols, 0, len(@cols)) --trim "," at end

set @query = 
'SELECT * from 
(
    select date, amount, category from #temp
) src
pivot 
(
    max(amount) for category in (' + @cols + ')
) piv'

execute(@query)
drop table #temp
```

Result

```
date                    ABC     DEF     GHI
2012-01-01 00:00:00.000 1000.00 NULL    NULL
2012-02-01 00:00:00.000 NULL    500.00  800.00
2012-02-10 00:00:00.000 NULL    700.00  NULL
2012-03-01 00:00:00.000 1100.00 NULL    NULL
```

Answer (score 23):

I know this question is older but I was looking thru the answers and thought that I might be able to expand on the "dynamic" portion of the problem and possibly help someone out.

First and foremost I built this solution to solve a problem a couple of coworkers were having with inconstant and large data sets needing to be pivoted quickly.

This solution requires the creation of a stored procedure so if that is out of the question for your needs please stop reading now.

This procedure is going to take in the key variables of a pivot statement to dynamically create pivot statements for varying tables, column names and aggregates. The Static column is used as the group by / identity column for the pivot(this can be stripped out of the code if not necessary but is pretty common in pivot statements and was necessary to solve the original issue), the pivot column is where the end resultant column names will be generated from, and the value column is what the aggregate will be applied to. The Table parameter is the name of the table including the schema (schema.tablename) this portion of the code could use some love because it is not as clean as I would like it to be. It worked for me because my usage was not publicly facing and sql injection was not a concern. The Aggregate parameter will accept any standard sql aggregate 'AVG', 'SUM', 'MAX' etc. The code also defaults to MAX as an aggregate this is not necessary but the audience this was originally built for did not understand pivots and were typically using max as an aggregate.

Lets start with the code to create the stored procedure. This code should work in all versions of SSMS 2005 and above but I have not tested it in 2005 or 2016 but I can not see why it would not work.

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_DYNAMIC_PIVOT]
    (
        @STATIC_COLUMN VARCHAR(255),
        @PIVOT_COLUMN VARCHAR(255),
        @VALUE_COLUMN VARCHAR(255),
        @TABLE VARCHAR(255),
        @AGGREGATE VARCHAR(20) = null
    )

AS


BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
declare @AVAIABLE_TO_PIVOT NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @SQLSTRING NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @PIVOT_SQL_STRING NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @TEMPVARCOLUMNS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @TABLESQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

if isnull(@AGGREGATE,'') = '' 
    begin
        SET @AGGREGATE = 'MAX'
    end


 SET @PIVOT_SQL_STRING =    'SELECT top 1 STUFF((SELECT distinct '', '' + CAST(''[''+CONVERT(VARCHAR,'+ @PIVOT_COLUMN+')+'']''  AS VARCHAR(50)) [text()]
                            FROM '+@TABLE+'
                            WHERE ISNULL('+@PIVOT_COLUMN+','''') <> ''''
                            FOR XML PATH(''''), TYPE)
                            .value(''.'',''NVARCHAR(MAX)''),1,2,'' '') as PIVOT_VALUES
                            from '+@TABLE+' ma
                            ORDER BY ' + @PIVOT_COLUMN + ''

declare @TAB AS TABLE(COL NVARCHAR(MAX) )

INSERT INTO @TAB EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL  @PIVOT_SQL_STRING, @AVAIABLE_TO_PIVOT 

SET @AVAIABLE_TO_PIVOT = (SELECT * FROM @TAB)


SET @TEMPVARCOLUMNS = (SELECT replace(@AVAIABLE_TO_PIVOT,',',' nvarchar(255) null,') + ' nvarchar(255) null')


SET @SQLSTRING = 'DECLARE @RETURN_TABLE TABLE ('+@STATIC_COLUMN+' NVARCHAR(255) NULL,'+@TEMPVARCOLUMNS+')  
                    INSERT INTO @RETURN_TABLE('+@STATIC_COLUMN+','+@AVAIABLE_TO_PIVOT+')

                    select * from (
                    SELECT ' + @STATIC_COLUMN + ' , ' + @PIVOT_COLUMN + ', ' + @VALUE_COLUMN + ' FROM '+@TABLE+' ) a

                    PIVOT
                    (
                    '+@AGGREGATE+'('+@VALUE_COLUMN+')
                    FOR '+@PIVOT_COLUMN+' IN ('+@AVAIABLE_TO_PIVOT+')
                    ) piv

                    SELECT * FROM @RETURN_TABLE'



EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQLSTRING

END
```

Next we will get our data ready for the example. I have taken the data example from the accepted answer with the addition of a couple of data elements to use in this proof of concept to show the varied outputs of the aggregate change.

```
create table temp
(
    date datetime,
    category varchar(3),
    amount money
)

insert into temp values ('1/1/2012', 'ABC', 1000.00)
insert into temp values ('1/1/2012', 'ABC', 2000.00) -- added
insert into temp values ('2/1/2012', 'DEF', 500.00)
insert into temp values ('2/1/2012', 'DEF', 1500.00) -- added
insert into temp values ('2/1/2012', 'GHI', 800.00)
insert into temp values ('2/10/2012', 'DEF', 700.00)
insert into temp values ('2/10/2012', 'DEF', 800.00) -- addded
insert into temp values ('3/1/2012', 'ABC', 1100.00)
```

The following examples show the varied execution statements showing the varied aggregates as a simple example. I did not opt to change the static, pivot, and value columns to keep the example simple. You should be able to just copy and paste the code to start messing with it yourself

```
exec [dbo].[USP_DYNAMIC_PIVOT] 'date','category','amount','dbo.temp','sum'
exec [dbo].[USP_DYNAMIC_PIVOT] 'date','category','amount','dbo.temp','max'
exec [dbo].[USP_DYNAMIC_PIVOT] 'date','category','amount','dbo.temp','avg'
exec [dbo].[USP_DYNAMIC_PIVOT] 'date','category','amount','dbo.temp','min'
```

This execution returns the following data sets respectively.

[image]

Comment: Good job! Can you please make an option of TVF instead of stored procedure. Would be convenient to select from such TVF.

Comment: Unfortunately not, to the best of my knowledge, because you cannot have a dynamic structure for a TVF. You have to have a static set of columns in a TVF.

Answer (score 20):

Updated version for SQL Server 2017 using STRING_AGG function to construct the pivot column list:

```
create table temp
(
    date datetime,
    category varchar(3),
    amount money
);

insert into temp values ('20120101', 'ABC', 1000.00);
insert into temp values ('20120201', 'DEF', 500.00);
insert into temp values ('20120201', 'GHI', 800.00);
insert into temp values ('20120210', 'DEF', 700.00);
insert into temp values ('20120301', 'ABC', 1100.00);


DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = (SELECT STRING_AGG(category,',') FROM (SELECT DISTINCT category FROM temp WHERE category IS NOT NULL)t);

set @query = 'SELECT date, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select date
                    , amount
                    , category
                from temp
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(amount)
                for category in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p ';

execute(@query);

drop table temp;
```

Comment: This is unfortunately a lot more painful to use than @mkdave99's answer. Firstly, if you need to order the pivot column list when building it, you need to remember the [stupid MSSQL hack of including `offset 0 rows`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44066528/70345). Secondly, you also have to remember the additional stupid MSSQL hack of including the unnecessary table alias `t`. Thirdly, it's also slightly slower than @mkdave99's answer.

Comment: @IanKemp To order rows, you *must* place `ORDER BY` on the *outside* of the query, no hacks needed. `ORDER BY` in a subquery, even with `OFFSET 0` just does not do what you think it does, it's only used to calculate the offset and which rows to return from the subquery, not the order they may come back in. Always use table aliases, they make code more readable, not sure why you think they're not necessary. mkdave99's answer uses variable coalescing, which is unreliable and can give incorrect results, particularly in the presence of `ORDER BY` see https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/132709/220697

Answer (score 4):

The below code provides the results which replaces **NULL** to **zero** in the output.

**Table creation and data insertion:**

```
create table test_table
 (
 date nvarchar(10),
 category char(3),
 amount money
 )

 insert into test_table values ('1/1/2012','ABC',1000.00)
 insert into test_table values ('2/1/2012','DEF',500.00)
 insert into test_table values ('2/1/2012','GHI',800.00)
 insert into test_table values ('2/10/2012','DEF',700.00)
 insert into test_table values ('3/1/2012','ABC',1100.00)
```

Query to generate the exact results which also replaces NULL with zeros:

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@PivotColumnNames AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@PivotSelectColumnNames AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column
SELECT @PivotColumnNames= ISNULL(@PivotColumnNames + ',','')
+ QUOTENAME(category)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT category FROM test_table) AS cat

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column with isnull
SELECT @PivotSelectColumnNames 
= ISNULL(@PivotSelectColumnNames + ',','')
+ 'ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(category) + ', 0) AS '
+ QUOTENAME(category)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT category FROM test_table) AS cat

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
N'SELECT date, ' + @PivotSelectColumnNames + '
FROM test_table
pivot(sum(amount) for category in (' + @PivotColumnNames + ')) as pvt';

--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

**OUTPUT :**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A version of [Taryn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10404455) with performance improvements:

### Data

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.Temp
(
    [date] datetime NOT NULL,
    category nchar(3) NOT NULL,
    amount money NOT NULL,

    INDEX [CX dbo.Temp date] CLUSTERED ([date]),
    INDEX [IX dbo.Temp category] NONCLUSTERED (category)
);

INSERT dbo.Temp
    ([date], category, amount)
VALUES
    ({D '2012-01-01'}, N'ABC', $1000.00),
    ({D '2012-01-02'}, N'DEF', $500.00),
    ({D '2012-01-02'}, N'GHI', $800.00),
    ({D '2012-02-10'}, N'DEF', $700.00),
    ({D '2012-03-01'}, N'ABC', $1100.00);
```

### Dynamic pivot

```sql
DECLARE 
    @Delimiter nvarchar(4000) = N',',
    @DelimiterLength bigint,
    @Columns nvarchar(max),
    @Query nvarchar(max);

SET @DelimiterLength = LEN(REPLACE(@Delimiter, SPACE(1), N'#'));

-- Before SQL Server 2017
SET @Columns =
    STUFF
    (
        (
            SELECT 
                [text()] = @Delimiter,
                [text()] = QUOTENAME(T.category)
            FROM dbo.Temp AS T
            WHERE T.category IS NOT NULL
            GROUP BY T.category
            ORDER BY T.category
            FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
        )
        .value(N'text()[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'),
        1, @DelimiterLength, SPACE(0)
    );

-- Alternative for SQL Server 2017+ and database compatibility level 110+
SELECT @Columns = 
    STRING_AGG(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), QUOTENAME(T.category)), N',')
        WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY T.category)
FROM 
(
    SELECT T2.category
    FROM dbo.Temp AS T2
    WHERE T2.category IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY T2.category
) AS T;

IF @Columns IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @Query = 
        N'SELECT [date], ' + 
        @Columns + 
        N' 
        FROM
        (
            SELECT [date], amount, category
            FROM dbo.Temp
        ) AS S
        PIVOT
        (
            MAX(amount)
            FOR category IN (' +
            @Columns +
            N')
        ) AS P;';

    EXECUTE sys.sp_executesql @Query;
END;
```

### Execution plans

[image: dynamic pivot execution plans]

### Results

| date | ABC | DEF | GHI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 1000.00 | NULL | NULL |
| 2012-01-02 00:00:00.000 | NULL | 500.00 | 800.00 |
| 2012-02-10 00:00:00.000 | NULL | 700.00 | NULL |
| 2012-03-01 00:00:00.000 | 1100.00 | NULL | NULL |

Answer (score 3):

There's my solution cleaning up the unnecesary null values

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@maxcols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(CodigoFormaPago) 
                from PO_FormasPago
                order by CodigoFormaPago
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

select @maxcols = STUFF((SELECT ',MAX(' + QUOTENAME(CodigoFormaPago) + ') as ' + QUOTENAME(CodigoFormaPago)
                from PO_FormasPago
                order by CodigoFormaPago
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT CodigoProducto, DenominacionProducto, ' + @maxcols + '
            FROM
            (
                SELECT 
                CodigoProducto, DenominacionProducto,
                ' + @cols + ' from 
                 (
                    SELECT 
                        p.CodigoProducto as CodigoProducto,
                        p.DenominacionProducto as DenominacionProducto,
                        fpp.CantidadCuotas as CantidadCuotas,
                        fpp.IdFormaPago as IdFormaPago,
                        fp.CodigoFormaPago as CodigoFormaPago
                    FROM
                        PR_Producto p
                        LEFT JOIN PR_FormasPagoProducto fpp
                            ON fpp.IdProducto = p.IdProducto
                        LEFT JOIN PO_FormasPago fp
                            ON fpp.IdFormaPago = fp.IdFormaPago
                ) xp
                pivot 
                (
                    MAX(CantidadCuotas)
                    for CodigoFormaPago in (' + @cols + ')
                ) p 
            )  xx 
            GROUP BY CodigoProducto, DenominacionProducto'

t @query;

execute(@query);
```

Answer (score 1):

Fully generic way that will work in non-traditional MS SQL environments (e.g. Azure Synapse Analytics Serverless SQL Pools) - it's in a SPROC but no need to use as such...

```
-- DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS
if object_id('dbo.usp_generic_pivot') is not null 
     DROP PROCEDURE dbo.usp_generic_pivot
GO;

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_generic_pivot (
    @source NVARCHAR (100), -- table or view object name
   @pivotCol NVARCHAR (100), -- the column to pivot
   @pivotAggCol NVARCHAR (100), -- the column with the values for the pivot
   @pivotAggFunc NVARCHAR (20), -- the aggregate function to apply to those values
   @leadCols NVARCHAR (100) -- comma seprated list of other columns to keep and order by
)
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @pivotedColumns NVARCHAR(MAX)
   DECLARE @tsql NVARCHAR(MAX)

   SET @tsql = CONCAT('SELECT @pivotedColumns = STRING_AGG(qname, '','') FROM (SELECT DISTINCT QUOTENAME(', @pivotCol,') AS qname FROM ',@source, ') AS qnames')
   EXEC sp_executesql @tsql, N'@pivotedColumns nvarchar(max) out', @pivotedColumns out

   SET @tsql = CONCAT ( 'SELECT ', @leadCols,   ',', @pivotedColumns,' FROM ',' ( SELECT ',@leadCols,',',
         @pivotAggCol,',',   @pivotCol,   ' FROM ',   @source,   ') as t ',
         ' PIVOT (', @pivotAggFunc,   '(', @pivotAggCol,   ')',' FOR ',   @pivotCol,
         '   IN (', @pivotedColumns,')) as pvt ',' ORDER BY ',   @leadCols)

   EXEC (@tsql)

END
GO;

-- TEST EXAMPLE
EXEC dbo.usp_generic_pivot  
    @source  = '[your_db].[dbo].[form_answers]',
   @pivotCol  = 'question', 
   @pivotAggCol   = 'answer',
   @pivotAggFunc  = 'MAX', 
   @leadCols    = 'candidate_id, candidate_name' 
GO;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #PivotExample(
   [ID]      [nvarchar](50)   NULL,       
   [Description]   [nvarchar](50)   NULL,
   [ClientId]   [smallint] NOT NULL,
)
GO


INSERT   #PivotExample  ([ID],[Description],   [ClientId])   VALUES ('ACI1','ACI1Desc1',1008)
INSERT   #PivotExample  ([ID],[Description],   [ClientId])   VALUES ('ACI1','ACI1Desc2',2000)
INSERT   #PivotExample  ([ID],[Description],   [ClientId])   VALUES ('ACI1','ACI1Desc3',3000)
INSERT   #PivotExample  ([ID],[Description],   [ClientId])   VALUES ('ACI1','ACI1Desc4',4000)
INSERT   #PivotExample  ([ID],[Description],   [ClientId])   VALUES ('ACI2','ACI2Desc1',5000)
INSERT   #PivotExample  ([ID],[Description],   [ClientId])   VALUES ('ACI2','ACI2Desc2',6000)
INSERT   #PivotExample  ([ID],[Description],   [ClientId])   VALUES ('ACI2','ACI2Desc3', 7000)

SELECT * FROM #PivotExample




--Declare necessary variables
DECLARE   @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE   @PivotColumns AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
 
--Get unique values of pivot column  
SELECT   @PivotColumns= COALESCE(@PivotColumns + ',','') + QUOTENAME([Description])
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Description] FROM [dbo].#PivotExample) AS PivotExample
 
--SELECT   @PivotColumns
 
--Create the dynamic query with all the values for 
--pivot column at runtime
SET   @SQLQuery = 
    N' -- Your pivoted result comes here
    SELECT ID, ' + @PivotColumns + '
    FROM 
    (
        -- Source table should in a inner query
        SELECT ID,[Description],[ClientId]
        FROM #PivotExample
    )AS P
    PIVOT
    (     
          -- Select the values from derived table P
          SUM(ClientId) 
          FOR [Description] IN (' + @PivotColumns + ') 
    )AS PVTTable'
 
--SELECT   @SQLQuery
--Execute dynamic query
EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery


Drop table #PivotExample
```