# PIVOT ouput in stored procedure in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [dynamic sql pivot in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327261/dynamic-sql-pivot-in-sql-server)

How to alter this stored procedure for PIVOT output

```
SELECT COUNT(Rly) AS TheCount, Rly FROM  SPAD 

WHERE  Rly IN ('CR', 'ER', 'ECR', 'ECoR', 'NR', 'NCR', 'SR', 'SCR', 'SER', 'SECR', 'WR', 'WCR', 'Kolkata') 


GROUP BY Rly
```

Comment: Are you wanting to pivot for each value of rly and have thecount show as its value? will rly ever have more values than what you listed?

Comment: Needs more details of desired results so we don't have to guess. Also have you tried anything yourself?  There are plenty of `PIVOT` examples [in BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ASSUMES that you have a finite number of rlys values;  The only other current way to achieve this is to use DYNAMIC SQL if there are more values.  (Searching for [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327261/dynamic-sql-pivot-in-sql-server))

```
Select
sum(case when rly = 'CR' then 1 else 0 end) as "CR",
sum(case when rly = 'ER' then 1 else 0 end) as "ER",
sum(case when rly = 'ECR' then 1 else 0 end) as "ECR",
sum(case when rly = 'ECoR' then 1 else 0 end) as "ECoR",
sum(case when rly = 'NR' then 1 else 0 end) as "NR",
sum(case when rly = 'NCR' then 1 else 0 end) as "NCR",
sum(case when rly = 'SR' then 1 else 0 end) as "SR",
sum(case when rly = 'SCR' then 1 else 0 end) as "SCR",
sum(case when rly = 'SER' then 1 else 0 end) as "SER",
sum(case when rly = 'SECR' then 1 else 0 end) as "SECR",
sum(case when rly = 'WR' then 1 else 0 end) as "WR",
sum(case when rly = 'WCR' then 1 else 0 end) as "WCR",
sum(case when rly = 'Kolkata' then 1 else 0 end) as "Kolkata"
FROM SPAD
```

EDITED After acceptance to change from count to sum.

Comment: Sir, both the solution works but gives total no. of Rly under each of Rly like CR 38, ER 38, ECR 38. Please help.

Comment: Thank you very much. Solution works as desired using SUM in place of count.

Comment: Keep in mind this will NOT work if your rly has MORE or values.  only DYNAMIC SQL will help you in that case.

Comment: Thanks again for your valuble comment, Sir.