# How to Pivot Column Headers in Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have table as following

```
   ID   FName    LName
   r1   Tom      Patrik
   r2   Jerry    Blaku
   r1   Ethan    Lie
```

I would like something as following

```
   ID      r1       r2      r1
   FName   Tom      Jerry   Ethan
   LName   Patrik   Blaku   Lie
```

NOTE THAT VALUES IN ID ARE NOT DISTINCT....!!
Is it possible to achieve this using sql Server Pivot(Or any) command,
If yes I will really appreciate TSQL for that

Comment: (duplicate) It's called a dynamic pivot. Take a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327261/dynamic-sql-pivot-in-sql-server http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/andras/archive/2007/09/14/37265.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I am sure there are better ways of doing this. But since you are trying to pivot multiple columns here is an ugly solution:

```
create table #temp
(
    id int,
    fname varchar(50),
    lname varchar(50)
)

insert into #temp values(1, 'Tom', 'Patrik')
insert into #temp values(2, 'Jerry', 'Blaku')

SELECT 'fname', P.Tom as '1', P.Jerry as '2'
FROM
(
    SELECT fname
    FROM #temp
) I
PIVOT
(
    min(fname)
    FOR [fname] IN ([Tom], [Jerry])
) as P
UNION
SELECT 'lname', P.Patrik as '1', P.Blaku as '2'
FROM
(
    SELECT lname
    FROM #temp
) I
PIVOT
(
    min(lname)
    FOR [lname] IN ([Patrik], [Blaku])
) as P

drop table #temp
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually have very complex query and I can not write pivot for each row. I mentioned very easy table just to get idea of how to do this using Pivot.

Comment: You can try using a dynamic sql pivot.